# Changing the value of a variable that is inside of a list without directly referencing the variable

Tags: python

I have a large list of variables, each of which needs to be assigned a random value.

I have been trying to change the value of the variables without going into individually changing each one to the selected random value.

However, it appears as if I have been going about this incorrectly.

```
Whales = 0

List = [Whales]

a = random.randint(1,10)

List[0] = a
```

Obviously this would change the 0 slot of List to a instead of changing the variable of Whales to a, so I was wondering how I would go about this without directly adding something like: Whales = a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need them to be variables, you can access them by name using a string. Otherwise go with the dictionary.

```
Whales = 6
var_list = ['Whales']
globals()[var_list[0]]
>>> 6
globals()[var_list[0]] = 7
globals()[var_list[0]]
>>> 7
```

Comment: If I have a list of variables, say: List = [Whales, Dolphins, Sharks] 
would it be possible to do this to each one of them without adding the string referencing the variable name?

Comment: Using this method, the list would have to be `['Whales', 'Dolphins', 'Sharks']` and you would use an element of the list (like `var_list[i]`) as the index to `globals()` as in `globals()[var_list[i]]`. I'm not advocating that you use this method unless you absolutely also need to be able to refer to the variables individually, like `Whales = 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can store your "variables" in a dict. Something like

```
import random

vars = ['whales', 'cats']
vars_dict = {v: random.randint(1, 10) for v in vars}
print(vars_dict)
```

output

```
{'whales': 3, 'cats': 5}
```